# updating a table using the max date and values from another table using sql in ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have with the following scenario: 
I want to update `tableB` using the rating from `tableA`. The challenge is: the ratings change randomly and when updating tableB's records, I have the take in account the date of the match and if the rating changed let's say on Tuesday and the game was on the monday before, I want the rating to be the previous rating not the latest one.

```
#table A: contains rating of players, changes randomly at any date depending
#on drop of form from the players  

PID| Rating | DateChange  |
1  |    2   | 10-May-2014 |
1  |    4   | 20-May-2015 |
1  |   20   | 1-June-2015 |
2  |    4   | 1-April-2014|
3  |    4   | 5-April-2014|
2  |    3   | 3-May-2015  |

#Table B: contains match sheets. Every player has a different match sheet
#and plays different dates.

MsID | PID  | MatchDate    | Win | Rating |
 1   |  2   | 10-May-2014  |  No |    0   |
 2   |  1   | 15-May-2015  | Yes |    0   |
 3   |  3   | 10-Apr-2014  |  No |    0   |
 4   |  1   | 21-Apr-2015  | Yes |    0   |
 5   |  1   | 3-June-2015  | Yes |    0   |
 6   |  2   | 5-May-2015   |  No |    0   |

#I am trying to achieve this by running the ms-access query: i want to get
#every players rating at the time the match was played not his current
#rating. 

MsID | PID  | MatchDate    | Rating |
 1   |  2   | 10-May-2014  |    4   |
 2   |  1   | 15-May-2015  |    2   |
 3   |  3   | 10-Apr-2014  |    4   |
 4   |  1   | 21-Apr-2015  |    2   |
 5   |  1   | 3-June-2015  |    20  |
 6   |  2   | 5-May-2015   |    3   |
```

I tried the following code:

```
Update [B-table] as wdev
set wdev.rating = ( SELECT B.MsID, B.PID, B.MatchDate, A.rating as Rating 
FROM [B-table] B
INNER JOIN [A-table] A
  on B.PID = A.PID
INNER JOIN (     
  SELECT MAX(Y.DateChange) MDC, Y.PID, Z.Matchdate
  FROM [B-table] Z
  INNER Join [A-table] Y
   on Z.PID = Y.PID
  and Y.DateChange <= Z.MatchDate
  GROUP BY Y.PID, Z.Matchdate) C
  on C.mdc = A.DateChange
 and A.PID = C.PId
 and B.MatchDate = C.Matchdate) And B.MsID = Wdev.MsID
```

### [SQLFiddle with database schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31717c)

**In summary: I want the rating corresponding to the max date change on or before date of match.**

Comment: in case you are wondering, this is similar to a question I have asked before but that one was about selecting not updating.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a correlated subquery:

```
update [B-table] as b
    set rating = (select top 1 rating
                  from [A-table] as a
                  where a.pid = b.pid and
                        a.datechange <= b.matchdate
                  order by a.datechange desc
                 ) ;
```

Note:  because of the way that MS Access processes `top`, the subquery could return multiple rows in the event of a tie.  The normal solution to this is to include an additional key value in the `order by`, to prevent ties.  However, there does not seem to be a unique key in the "a" table.

Comment: +1 for the result. I will try it in access and see what happens. It works already with my sqlFiddle. thanks